# Matplotlib histogram - plotting values greater than a given value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've the following histogram:
[image]

It was produced with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as num


treshold_file='false_alarms.txt'
with open(treshold_file, 'r') as f2:
    lines = f2.readlines()
data = [line.split() for line in lines]
data1 = num.array(data)
data2= data1.astype(float)
plt.hist((data2), alpha=0.4,bins=[100,110,120,130,   140,150,160,180,200,250,300,350,400])
plt.xlabel("treshold")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
```

I'd like to plot for each bin the number of values greater or equal  to a given treshold.

For the bin 100, I'd like to plot the number of samples > 100, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a manual `bar` plot after constructing the necessary data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy data
data2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=450, size=200)

bins = [100,110,120,130,140,150,160,180,200,250,300,350,400]
bincenters = (np.array(bins)[1:] + bins[:-1])/2
binwidths = np.diff(bins)
binvals = [np.sum(data2>=thresh) for thresh in bins[:-1]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(bincenters, binvals, width=binwidths, alpha=0.4,
       edgecolor=['darkblue'])
ax.set_xlabel('threshold')
ax.set_ylabel('occurences')
ax.autoscale('x', tight=True)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: bar plot]

The array `bins` is actually the list (`ndarray`) of thresholds. For each threshold we compute the number of values of `data2` which are above the threshold, these are the values of the bar plot, called `binvals`. We skip the last indices, to get the correct dimensions in the output. The auxiliary array `bincenters` contains the midpoint of each bin (by taking the mean of the two corresponding edges).

Comment: What is bincenters here?

Comment: @ohsoifelse thanks again for the question, I had to change a few things (and rewrite the snippet while I was at it).